# Grouped Table in Monotouch with MvvmCross

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

How do you implement a view with a grouped table in MonoTouch using MvvmCross, so you get something like this:

http://www.yetanotherchris.me/storage/downloads/UITableViewController.png

Right now I have this piece of code, but I cannot change the UITableViewStyle to Grouped:

```
public partial class HomeView : MvxBindingTouchTableViewController<HomeViewModel>
{
    public HomeView(MvxShowViewModelRequest request)
        : base(request)
    {

    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItem(new UIBarButtonItem("History", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, (sender, e) => ViewModel.DoGoToHistory()), false);

        var source = new MvxActionBasedBindableTableViewSource(
            TableView,
            UITableViewCellStyle.Value1,
            new NSString("HomeView"),
            "{'TitleText':{'Path':'Date'},'DetailText':{'Path':'Location'},'SelectedCommand':{'Path':'ViewDetailCommand'}}",
            UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator);

        this.AddBindings(
            new Dictionary<object, string>()
            {
            { source, "{'ItemsSource':{'Path':'List'}}" },
            { this, "{'Title':{'Path':'TestTitle'}}"}
        });

        TableView.Source = source;
        TableView.ReloadData();
    }
}
```

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your picture shows only one section.... assuming you are looking for just one section, but this grouped styling, then all you need to do is to introduce UITableViewStyle.Grouped somehow.

I'm not sure that the current MvxTableViewController exposes this for you - so you might either need to edit the Mvx source to add the appropriate constructors:

```
    protected MvxTouchTableViewController(MvxShowViewModelRequest request, UITableViewStyle style = UITableViewStyle.Plain)
        : base(style)
    {
        ShowRequest = request;
    }
```

and

```
    protected MvxBindingTouchTableViewController(MvxShowViewModelRequest request, UITableViewStyle style = UITableViewStyle.Plain)
        : base(request, style)
    {
    }
```

---

Alternatively you could use a basic view controller (in which you add a Table as a subview) instead of a tableview derived view controller.

---

If you want multiple Groups, then you'll need to do a bit more work - as you'll need to work out how the bound TableViewSource works out the number of sections and the number of items in each section.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Maybe a silly question @Stuart, but how to add a table as a subview and use the MvvmCross binding. Can you still use the MvxActionBasedBindableTableViewSource?

Comment: Create the uiableview with its position(frame), set it's source, then use addsubview?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class UserView : MvxTableViewController<UserViewModel>
    {
        public UserView()
            :base(UITableViewStyle.Grouped)
        {
        }
    }
```

Remember to make the constructor public and parameterless.